# GWT CellTable with checkbox selection and on row click event

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

How to call a method when some row is clicked using the checkbox selection model?

I'm setting the checkbox selection model like this:

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, 
      DefaultSelectionEventManager.<T> createCheckboxManager(0));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution! Instead of using `createCheckboxManager()`,  use `createCustomManager()` passing by argument an `EventTranslator` that extends the `CheckboxEventTranslator` and do a delegation of the `translateSelectionEvent` method, intercepting only the events ignored by the super (`CheckboxEventTranslator`).

The source code:

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, 
    DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCustomManager(
        new DefaultSelectionEventManager.CheckboxEventTranslator<T>() {
            @Override
            public SelectAction translateSelectionEvent(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
                SelectAction action = super.translateSelectionEvent(event);
                if (action.equals(SelectAction.IGNORE)) {
                    GWT.log("DO WHAT YOU WANT!!!");
                    return SelectAction.IGNORE;
                }
                return action;
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that you call,

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, ClassName.myMethod(0));

static <T> DefaultSelectionEventManager<T> myMethod(int column) {
   //call whatever functions you want
   return DefaultSelectionEventManager.<T> createCheckboxManager(column);
}
```