# table with multiselection and clickable row

Tags: gwt

I already have a table - CellTable, with single selection model and i used onSelectionChange to find when row was clicked

Next I added to that column which containes check box
and here comes my problem

if i use single selection model, when i tick one row, other row become unticked

i tried to switch to multiselection model, but in this case, i can't click on row, and onSelectionChanges is executed only when i click on my check box, but i can tick more than one box

is any chance how i can have both - multiselection and clickable row?
regards

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637598/gwt-celltable-with-checkbox-selection-and-on-row-click-event ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
But I am suprised that it doesn't work because the default behavior of the MultiSelectionModel should be that the row is selected as soon as you click it. However maybe in the presence of a CheckBoxCell column it is different.

Anyways you have to check following JavaDocs:

- [Constructor of the CheckboxCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CheckboxCell.html#CheckboxCell%28boolean,%20boolean%29)
- [DefaultSelectionEventManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html)

Comment: i needed to have option of selection row, and perform action if row was clicked. I solve this by multiselect for row selection and CellPreviewEvent. Works fine to me:)